# How does one handle Webhooks in BrainTree

Tags: php, webhooks, braintree

I am trying to use the BrainTree webhooks for subscription transactions but have been unable to get my page to verify.

From BrainTree: https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/webhooks/destination_verification

When you attempt to add the destination, our servers will make a GET request to the provided URL with a query param named bt_challenge. This query param should be passed to the verify method. The result of calling this method should be returned as the body of the response.

```
Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify(bt_challenge_param);
```

First, I tried in NodeJS (as our transactions are successfully done this way):

```
//WEBHOOK GET PROCESS FOR BRAINTREE SUBSCRIPTION
app.get('/getwebhook', function(req, res){

    var bt_challenge_param = req.param('bt_challenge_param', null);
    var jsObj = new Object();

    jsObj.response = gateway.webhookNotification.verify(bt_challenge_param);

    res.json(JSON.stringify(jsObj));
});
```

where my PHP page communicated with the NodeJS process and puts the result in the body. Once this failed verification, I wrote a test page directly in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('production');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('mymid');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('mypubkey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('myprodkey');

$bt_challenge = "";
if(isset($_GET['bt_challenge']))
{
    $bt_challenge = $_GET['bt_challenge'];
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>Webhooks</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($bt_challenge) && $bt_challenge != ""){
    echo Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($bt_challenge);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this too failed verification. Not sure what is wrong as there is no test for verification or any indication of what is wrong. I tried contacting BrainTree support but with no response back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the result of

```
Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($bt_challenge);
```

as the [body of the response](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/webhooks/destination_verification), not the body of an HTML document that is in turn the body of the response. In other words, your entire file should be something like:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('production');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('mymid');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('mypubkey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('myprodkey');

$bt_challenge = "";
if(isset($_GET['bt_challenge']))
{
    $bt_challenge = $_GET['bt_challenge'];
}
if(isset($bt_challenge) && $bt_challenge != ""){
    echo Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($bt_challenge);
}
?>
```

If you have any more questions, please feel free to reach out to [Braintree Support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/support).

Disclosure: I work at Braintree.