# Webhook Destination could not be verified

Tags: php, zend-framework, webhooks, braintree

Good day.

I am integrating braintree  with zend framework.

now, need to integrate webhook.

I have created a controller (test) and function (webhook1)
in function (webhook1) it automatically calls a view file (default zend structure).

View file name is webhook1.phtml

my webhook1.phtml look like below

```
 <?php 
require_once LIB_PATH.'NIC/Payment/Gateway/braintree/braintree-php/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('merchantid');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('publickey');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('privatekey');


$bt_challenge = "";
if(isset($_GET['bt_challenge']))
{
    $bt_challenge = $_GET['bt_challenge'];
}
if(isset($bt_challenge) && $bt_challenge != ""){
    echo Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($bt_challenge);
}

    ?>
```

i can run this file on my server successfully. (http://www.website.com/projectname/public/test/webhook1?bt_challenge=1)

Am i missing something here ?
why braintree is not able to verify url ?

I took reference from here : [How does one handle Webhooks in BrainTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461094/how-does-one-handle-webhooks-in-braintree)

Any help will appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I work at Braintree. You don't really provide enough information here for us to help you. When you try to verify from the control panel, what do you see in your server log? What does the control panel say? I'd recommend you [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/); they can help you more.

Comment: Hi agf, 
Control panel says -- Destination could not be verified.
and i have not tracked server log yet in my code.

Comment: Without seeing what error your code is getting we don't have enough info to help you. Your best bet is to email our support team.

Comment: I Simply call my webhook file directly like http://www.website.com/projectname/webhooks.php 

Not used MVC architecture. --- and it verified successfully. 

So, may be there is some issue at braintree side or in my code, when i try to call same file using MVC architecture.